# I used INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY. Now how do I access that file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

New obviously to HDFS, not even sure what to search for to get help for this.

Most of my tables are within databases under user/hive/warehouse in HDFS.  I wanted to store a SELECT result into a directory I had write access to, so I stored it into user/Jon/folder_name, and that worked.

Now how do I access the data in this file?  The working directory is user/hive/warehouse, and I didn't create a table within the /Jon/folder_name folder (it's just a file).  I'm trying to run a basic SELECT count(*) from folder_name and I don't know where to start to get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon, I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it would definitely serve the purpose.

As soon as you are done with the `insertion`, you will get a file like `000000_0` inside the target directory. I know it's wired, but the filename is 000000_0. If your query had more than 1 reducers then you would get multiple files like 000000_0, 000001_0, 000002_0 and so on.

Assuming that you had issued following query which had 1 reducer :

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/Jon/folder_name' SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Now create an `external table` using `/Jon/folder_name/000000_0` as its location and then do the select. Like this :

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name2(id INT, name STRING) LOCATION '/Jon/folder_name/000000_0';
```

And then,

```
hive> select count(*) from table_name2;
```

HTH